# Why Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) infers T as Object for a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, comparator

Say if I want to sort a 2d array. (just reorder the rows, don't touch data within each row).

In following snippet: all 3 cases use the same `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` method signature. Case (a) works fine. However, just **by adding a if condition to the second argument, the inference of T changes**. I couldn't comprehend why.

```
        // array contains 3 tuples, sort it by the first element, then second element
        int[][] array1 = new int[3][2];
        array1[0] = new int[]{1,2};
        array1[1] = new int[]{2,3};
        array1[2] = new int[]{2,4};

        // Case (a): compiles good, tuple is inferred as int[]
        Arrays.sort(array1, Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]));  // Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) correctly infers that T refers to int[]

        // Case (b.1): compile error: incompatible types
        // tuple is now inferred as Object, why?
        Arrays.sort(array1,
                (a1, a2) -> a1[0] == a2[0] ?
                        Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[1]) : Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]));  

        // Case (b.2): compile error: incompatible types
        Arrays.sort(array1, Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]).thenComparingInt(tuple -> tuple[1])); 
        
        // Case (c): if downcast tuple[0] to ((int[])tuple)[0], then (b) works fine.
```

Update:

1. Enlightened by the comments, I soon realized that case (b.1) is actual not valid.
   The lambda in (b.1) suppose to return an integer, not a comparator. E.g.
   `Arrays.sort(array1, (a1, a2) -> a1[0] == a2[0] ? 0 : 1);`
2. In all other scenarios, I see `Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(...)` forces the inference correctly.

Comment: Most likely because when you use a ternary `condition ? a : b`, the result of `a` and `b` have to line up in their types. So both `Comparator.comparingInt(...)` calls have to be lined up and most likely the complex rules for that process fail and decide that `Object` is the only way to ensure this.

Comment: Note that you can specify the type you want manually if the auto-infer fails like here. `Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(...)`. Looks weird, but works.

Comment: Interesting how just doing `Arrays.sort(array1, Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]))`, without `thenComparingInt`, works.

Comment: Anyway, you can just do `Arrays.sort(array1, Arrays::compare);` if you want a lexicographical order. No need for all this `thenComparing` stuff.

Comment: @Sweeper `Arrays` doesn't have a `compare` method. maybe you're referring to some specific array comparator impl? I don't see how a general lexicographical comparator can compare two int[] based on its elements? (e.g.`Arrays.sort(array1)` will give runtime error when it tries to cast int[] to Comparable. )

Comment: @WeishiZ It does have a `compare` method in Java 9. I didn't realise you are using Java 8, sorry.

Comment: @Sweeper Ah I just looked at java 9 and `Arrays:compare` does exactly the job to compare all primitive arrays. Good to know and thanks for the reference!

Comment: A general Java 8 alternative to `Arrays::compare` would be `Comparator.comparing(IntBuffer::wrap)`. But when the arrays are known to always have two elements, I’d keep `Comparator.comparingInt((int[] a)->a[0]).thenComparingInt(a->a[1])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the compiler is not smart enough to infer through such complex expressions. It needs some help inferring the type:

```
Arrays.sort(array1, Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]).thenComparingInt(tuple -> tuple[1]));
```

Related JEP: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101

As for the ternary expression case, I think it needs further adaptation, since you need to return an `int` in the lambda, not a `Comparator`:

```
Arrays.sort(array1,
            (a1, a2) -> a1[0] == a2[0] ?
                    Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[1]).compare(a1, a2) :
                    Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]).compare(a1, a2));
```

Comment: (It might be that OP was aware of that and wanted to know the exact reasons and rules that lead to this (i.e. the long answer), rather than a way to fix it.)

Comment: You can also use `Arrays.sort(array1, Comparator.comparingInt((int[] tuple) -> tuple[0]) .thenComparingInt(tuple -> tuple[1]));`

Answer (score 0):

After digging a bit further, here's an intuitive explanation on this behavior:

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
...
default Comparator<T> thenComparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)
public static <T> Comparator<T> comparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor)
...
}
```

1. The `public static` method needs the caller to define `T` (as goes by the first `<T>` in the second method) when invoking the method. Otherwise it defaults to `Object`.
2. This is unlike the non-static method, where `T` is already defined during instantiation.

So looking at `Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]);`, compiler won't know what `T` is and hence defaults to `Object`.

To properly feed compiler the actual type `T`,  we can explicitly define T in different places.

```
// define T when calling the method
Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]); 

// infer by return type, this is samilar to placing the rhs to Arrays.sort(int[][] a, rhs)
Comparator<int[]> c = Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0]); 

// explicit target type for lambda expression
Comparator.comparingInt((ToIntFunction<int[]>) tuple -> tuple[0]);

// explicit type for lambda parameter
Comparator.comparingInt((int[] tuple) -> tuple[0]);

// This works but it's doesn't change the inference of T as comments suggests below.
Comparator.comparingInt(tuple -> ((int[])tuple)[0]);
```

Once it returns a `Comparator<int[]>` object (thus defined `T` as `int[]`), the instance method `thenComparingInt` is called upon knowing what T is.

Comment: Doing a type cast *within* the lambda expression is not a good idea. It doesn’t change what type the compiler infers, so it produces `(Object tuple) -> ((int[])tuple)[0]`, doing an actual cast. Then, the compiler will not warn you when the array to sort has the wrong type. The actual alternatives to assignment are: `Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(tuple -> tuple[0])` (explicit type for `T`), `Comparator.comparingInt((int[] tuple) -> tuple[0])` (explicit type for lambda parameter), or `Comparator.comparingInt((ToIntFunction<int[]>)tuple -> tuple[0])` (explicit target type for lambda expression).

Comment: @Holger I think you're right, it'll produce a `Object -> int` lambda and that doesn't define T in any sense. Adapted your comments into the answer above.